how can I update flutter app on play store?
how can I use my existing keystore in my flutter project to build and release my update to play store? I'm beginner and still learning...
"my code was with another developer"
I don't know how to use the key.jks file, or if it the file that contains those keys:
storePassword=\<password-from-previous-step\> keyPassword=\<password-from-previous-step\> keyAlias=upload storeFile=\<keystore-file-location\>your text``
